# Composer - SensioDistributionBundle asking for a password

Tags: git, symfony, composer-php

I just did a `Composer install` and it crashes with the following error:

> - Removing sensio/distribution-bundle (v2.1.11)
> - Installing sensio/distribution-bundle (v2.1.7)
>     Downloading: connection...
>     Could not fetch https://api.github.com/repos/sensio/SensioDistributionBundle/zip
>     ball/v2.1.7, enter your GitHub credentials to access private repos
>     The credentials will be swapped for an OAuth token stored in C:/Users/PC/A
>     ppData/Roaming/Composer/config.json, your password will not be stored
>     To revoke access to this token you can visit https://github.com/settings/applica
>     tions
>     Username:

And it just doesnt continues. I've done some google and no answer.

Any idea?

Edit:

As someone requested, this is the .lock file of composer. Note that it's huge:
http://pastebin.com/YpqPn0P9

Comment: Can you show us your composer.lock file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's solved now.

I decided to remove all vendors manually and then do a full download of vendors.

It's solved now.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes github has problem serving .zip of the repository.

You should use `php composer.phar install --prefer-source` to avoid getting "could not fetch.......".

This option tells composer to clone the repository instead of trying to download the archive.

Comment: same happens: `Could not fetch https://api.github.com/repos/sensio/SensioDistributionBundle/zip
ball/v2.1.7, enter your GitHub credentials to access private repos` I will edit my question with the code of .lock file

Answer (score 1):

If you use Github too much from your IP address, you will at some point exceed the anonymous API access limits.

One way around it is to have a Github account and authenticate with your credentials.

The other alternative is to wait until the anonymous access lock is released.

Comment: Are you sure I will have access to the repository if I login with an account?

Comment: No. When I ran into it, the time it took to google for the reason was enough time to release the lock again. And I hadn't had my credentials with me when it happened.